# Convert DD-MON-YY String to Date

Tags: date, go

I read multiple blogs, pages but can't exactly find how to convert the string in the format of DD-MON-YYYY format to GoLangs time.Time.

Sample strings:

> 1) 1-Nov-17 
>  2) 15-Nov-17

Once I can convert above to GoLang date then I can parse it using below, but I can't find the full solution, please help.

```
convertedDateString := dateStamp.Format("2-Jan-06")
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/yTp9Oi_K5x

Comment: Brilliant @zerkms!